# How can i solve Error : UPS connected By API - Calculate Rates Error

Tags: magento-1.9, api, shipping-methods, ups

The API is connected successfully, when i try to test, its not working. 
How can i solve Error

**Note** :

```
1)Without Products Weight UPS Rates Should be Displayed 
2)After give weight to products, the UPS weight not calculated.
```

[image]

Comment: how you find api connected successfully ?

Comment: As i mentioned above, supposed if not set weight for products, its display UPS rates, right after i set weight for products, its not working ...

Comment: are your talking about Maximum Package Weight ? & Minimum Package Weight

Comment: No bro, i have set maximum and minimum weight. My error is, when i try to test shipping to usa, shipping rates not calculted

Comment: I mean UPS API is not calculated Shipping Rates.

Comment: check Ship to Applicable Countries  option for USA

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46971/how-can-i-solve-ups-connected-by-api-error-calculate-rates-error

Comment: could you pls join the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46976/discussion-between-lalit-mohan-and-jeeva-rathinam).